Finish one iteration after KeyboardInterrupt (or similar interruption)
I have written a program because I need to unpack a massive amount of zip archives:
zip_folder = "zips"
for zip_file in os.listdir(zip_folder):
    path_zip_file = os.path.join(zip_folder, zip_file)
    with zipfile.ZipFile(path_zip_file, "r") as zip_ref:
        zip_ref.extractall("extract_folder")

    os.remove(path_zip_file)


However sometimes I want to interrupt the program. I would like to interrupt the program in a way that after I interrupt the program the running iteration is still finished so that I can easily restart to program without having to deal with half-extracted files.
I do not want to catch an exception because this still leaves half-extracted zips files. A not so beautiful way would be to just write a letter in a text file and let the program at the beginning of each iteration check if a letter is present.
Is there any proper, elegant way to achieve this?

You can use a signal handler and set a break condition.

An easier way than to finish the running iteration is to erase the running iteration. The result is the same - there will be no half-extracted files. This can be achieved in many ways. You can register a cleanup function to run at script exit, you can extract the files into a temporary directory first, ...
